# How can I use Arduino Analog Uno pins as Digital pins?

Tags: arduino-uno, pins, atmega328, raspberrypi, iot

How can I use Arduino Uno Analog Pins as Digital pins, So that I can Attach more components like sensors to the Arduino? My 13 pins are preoccupied and I want more.

Comment: with `digitalWrite` and `digitalRead`. what is your question? https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/digital-io/digitalwrite/#_notes_and_warnings

Comment: For Arduino Uno

Comment: yes for Uno. you tagged the question with [arduino-uno]

Comment: Can you provide me any code sample as an instance

Comment: Any of the analog pins (with exception of A6 and A7) can also be used as digital pins, just like any other pin of the Arduino. Just use `pinMode()`, `digitalWrite()` and `digitalRead()` on them, as you like.

Comment: Thank you Juraj and chrisl